# How to automatically hide hidden files at boot?

Tags: nautilus, security, gnome-terminal, hidden-files

Sometimes when I boot up my machine, hidden folders and files are not hidden... I can ctrl+h to hide them again, but it is a security issue to *have* to do this. Likewise, if I `ls` in terminal (no flags) while this is going on, my hidden files (prefixed with `.` will appear, even without the `-a` flag). I unchecked the "show" option in nautilus, but I don't know where to go from there. Could there be another program that is triggering this?

EDIT: The behavior I was experiencing before seems to have resolved itself. According to another post (that I saw at school and cannot remember the location of) nautilus *sometimes* saves settings like this, and other times does not. My guess is that either in nautilus or another program, I `ctrl+H`'d or something equivalent, and my system saved this setting, but did not save it (right away) when I tried to stop this behavior. Not sure exactly why gnome-terminal was displaying hidden files, or why it stopped, but with the problem gone for the time being, I cannot test it or properly fix it (at least until the problem arises again).

Comment: Why is it a security issue?

Comment: if this thing happen with "ls", could you please do an "alias ls" and "where ls" for checking what "ls" command is used ? Please post the result.
In general the files starting with a "." are simply not hidden but most of the programs will not show them (exclude all files starting with a dot in there file name). Well, thats not secure...more organizing things. So maybe it is disturbing the file organization of files if they get displayed.

Comment: alias ls='ls --color=auto'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the "dconf editor" using the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

open dconf editor using the command:

```
 dconf-editor
```

Browse to org > gtk > settings > file-chooser

Uncheck the "hidden file" key appearing in right side.
Done !!

Comment: how is this different than setting directly from nautilus menu?

Comment: I had this problem... Nautilus doesnt fix this.. dconf tools,deals with your system files. Try it

Comment: @botch..it should solve your problem if it does plz consider accepting as solution and select √ so as to mark this thread as solved